# How to get the width of padding, border, and margins of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently I'm doing some pretty nasty calculations to get the actual width of a `<select>` element. It has border, padding, margin, etc. jQuery's outerWidth() - innerWidth() doesn't give me nearly what I'm looking for. Has anyone encountered this type of issue before? Seems like it'd actually be common.

Comment: Are you set true in outerWidth? http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/

Answer (score 1):

Try this [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/jamierumbelow/jquery.computed-style) that will allow you to get the computed CSS of elements and may help solve your problem.